# How can I remove this yellow box around my image tag?

Tags: jquery, css, image, jquery-ui

I'm using the jQueryUI datepicker widget,

```
  $(function() {
      $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
          showOn: "button",
          //buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
          buttonImageOnly: true,
          buttonText: "Select date"
      });
 });
```

If I remove the buttonImage attribute from the datepicker, I am able to set the image through CSS

```
.ui-datepicker-trigger { 
    background-image: url("images/calendar.gif",);
}
```

This approach leaves me with a yellow box around the image. This is becuse the img element has no image assigned to it's src attribute and instead has a background image.

This approach is wrong, but if I had to use it, which means removing the image from the jQuery and adding it only through CSS, is there any way to remove the yellow box around my image?

```
border:0 does not work.
```

Cheers!

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ktrae6ue/)**

In the fiddle, you can see the border clearly. If you uncomment the jQuery img part, it overrides the CSS and the border no longer appears.

Comment: you have two quotes in your background-image:url( "" images/

Comment: Added a jsfiddle @Rooster

Comment: I still don't undesrtand why don't use the line of jquery to change the image ? http://jsfiddle.net/ktrae6ue/2/

Comment: @Danko The path between the image and the page is subject to change. The path from the CSS to the image will never change. It's an odd situation I know. I'm just wondering if there is a fix available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just for fun, as an alternative to Josh Burgess answer, I was able to accomplish your desired goal by doing the following with pure css and commenting out buttonImageTrue:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ktrae6ue/4/)

updated js

```
  $(function() {
      $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
          showOn: "button",
          //buttonImage: "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/aa/Wink(16px).svg",
          //buttonImageOnly: true,
          buttonText: "Select date"
      });
 });
```

CSS

```
.ui-datepicker-trigger { 
    background-image: url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/aa/Wink(16px).svg");
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    color: transparent;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

New answer, because the approach you're taking is interesting and I generally wouldn't recommend it.  *However...*

**[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ktrae6ue/3/)**

Here's everything we changed:

```
$(function() {
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      showOn: "button",
      buttonImage: "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7",
      buttonImageOnly: true,
      buttonText: "Select date"
  });
});
```

Pay special attention to that new button image: `data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7`

This is the Base64 encode of a 1px by 1px transparent image.  That's going to wipe out the empty src default rendering for an image, allowing the background image of the image to show unabated.

I would not recommend using an image as a background imaged button element unless absolutely necessary in the future, however, as not only is it semantically incorrect but also will inevitably present some cross-browser issues.  Fair warning.

## TL;DR: This works, but YMMV

Comment: holy base64 encoding batman!  thats wild.  I wouldn't have though to try that.  nice ++

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just add this to your CSS

```
#datepicker button img {
    display: none!important;
}
```

Without some example code, I'm afraid that's the best I'll be able to offer.

Comment: This will just remove the image... I want to remove the border but keep the image.

Comment: Well, hold on.  You're not setting a background-image on the image, are you?  Because that's not right and you shouldn't be doing that.  It seems like you're replacing the img tag in the original plugin with a background-image.  If that's not the case, can you clarify further in your question?

Comment: "This approach is wrong, but if I had to use it, which means removing the image from the jQuery and adding it only through CSS, is there any way to remove the yellow box around my image?"

Comment: Alright, check my second answer coming in a second, then.